# Regd not able to parse date :

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a RC3339 time format to MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a but it shows null value at sampleDate.

```
timestamp = rcobj.getString("timestamp");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSZ", Locale.US);
Date sampleDate = sdf.parse(timestamp, new ParsePosition(0));
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);
if (timestamp != null) {
    timestamp = sdf.format(sampleDate);
}
```

Comment: And what's the value of `timestamp`? And why are you parsing it if it might be null, without checking first? (Also, I'm assuming this is Java, but it would help if you'd tagged it that way...)

Answer (score 0):

If `timestamp` is an invalid date, the [parse method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) throws a [`ParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html), so it's not that.

If `timestamp` is `null`, `parse()` throws a [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

I can pretty much guarantee that `rcobj.getString("timestamp")` is returning `null`.

BTW `parse(timestamp, new ParsePosition(0))` is equivalent to simply `parse(timestamp)`.

Comment: The time stamp had value like this : 2012-01-19T18:23:43+0000.But it is fixed now by changing the pattern of the string IN SimpleDateFormat.I was using this : yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSZ Instead it works when i use yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss It doesn't match the pattern of offset with my timestamp string.When i changed the pattern it works fine.Thats for helping me out.